# value does not fall within expected range

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a windows phone project.  I have a listbox with the following selectionchanged event handler:

```
private void judgeType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadJudgeCategories(judgeTypeListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Here is the LoadJudgeCategories method:

```
void LoadJudgeCategories(string judgeType)
{
    string[] categories = judgeCategories[judgeType];
    List<LabeledTextBox> itemSource = new List<LabeledTextBox>();
    foreach (string cat in categories)
    {
        itemSource.Add(new LabeledTextBox(cat));
    }
    CategoryPanel.ItemsSource = itemSource;
}
```

judgeCategories is of type

```
Dictionary<string, string[]>
```

LabeledTextBox is usercontrol with a textblock and a textbox.  CategoryPanel is just a listbox.

Whenever the selected item is changed, I want to clear CategoryPanel, and replace it with a new List.

Occasionally, however, when I change the selection, it gives the exception "value does not fall within the expected range".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you add multiple controls with the same name. Try this code. Broken down with newlines for clarity. I turned it into a linq statement, and also named each of the `LabeledTextBox` something random.
Note: the only important thing I did was give the `LabeledTextBox` a name.

```
Random r = new Random();
void LoadJudgeCategories(string judgeType)
{
    CategoryPanel.ItemsSource =
        judgeCategories[judgeType]
        .Select(cat => 
            new LabeledTextBox(cat) { Name = r.Next().ToString() }
        ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't r.Next() be in danger of giving the same result twice?

Comment: no, because the next value is seeded off of the last random value, so... bassically no, However If you wanted to you could just use some counting int in the back instead, which when it reaches int.MaxValue, just set it equal to int.MinValue

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution with `ObservableCollection` - there will be no need to set `CategoryPanel.ItemsSource` multiple times:

```
private ObservableCollection<LabeledTextBox> itemSource = new ObservableCollection<LabeledTextBox>();

CategoryPanel.ItemsSource = itemSource; // somewhere in the Constructor

void LoadJudgeCategories(string judgeType) 
{
  itemSource.Clear();
  foreach (string cat in judgeCategories[judgeType])
    itemSource.Add(new LabeledTextBox(cat));
}
```